# How to scroll views inside a circular layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-scrollview

I have to design a screen for tablet application in which a big circle has some items (menus), these item should be scroll horizontally. Please see image below:

[image]

There are two requirement related to scrolling:

1. Middle items should be bigger than other items when scrolling.
2. First item and last item of inside circle should be hide according to edge of circle. It should not be hide according to a rectangular edge.

These two requirement are the problem. Please suggest how can I achieve these task.

**This the layout of the circle:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_allCategory"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_all_category" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_allCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="all\ndrinks"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv_allCategory"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_allCategory"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_sprite_zero" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_sprite" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_fanta" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **View Pager** and customise the view pager to acomplish your task. I have done the same thing in one of my projects. Look at the documentation `http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html` and play with it. You'll be able to accomplish it.

Comment: Can I achieve 2nd task also with View Pager?

Comment: Place the View pager below the Circular image with the circle cut (transparent and rest same as BG color

Comment: Ya Both tasks you can achieve

Comment: Okay, Thank you for replying, will acknowledge you after doing this with some points : )

Comment: I got one more requirement that is the small circles will be scrolling automatically like marquee. Can we do this also with view pager?

Comment: Yes you can. You have to call mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1); in a thread for ever a defined period of time.

Comment: I have tried it but not getting the result.. can you give an example

Comment: You got to experiment by creating a custom PageTransformer  and FragmentStatePagerAdapter classes and set it for the ViewPager that you create